# jquery html string attribute selection

Tags: jquery

i have jquery string which have html ,

```
btn_response = '<input type="button" id="upload-btn5" style="margin-bottom: 7px;" class="btn btn-success clearfix" value="Choose file">';
```

the id attribute change every time , so i wonder how i can get id attribute value from that jquery string.

i tried

```
$(uploadBtn).data("id")
```

output

```
undefined
```

but no success !

can anybody help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doatwc8s/  `$(uploadBtn).data("id")` will select attribute `data-id` and `$(uploadBtn).attr("id")` will select id attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the string in jQuery and get the id of element.

```
$(btn_response).attr('id');
```

`data()` is used to get `data-*` attribute value. Use `attr` to get the `id` attribute value.

`$(uploadBtn).data("id")` will search for `data-id` attribute, which is not available so returns `undefined`.

Use:

```
$(uploadBtn).attr("id")
```

Demo:

```js
var btn_response = '<input type="button" id="upload-btn5" style="margin-bottom: 7px;" class="btn btn-success clearfix" value="Choose file">';

alert($(btn_response).attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```